# Google Maps API - Retail locations

Tags: ios, google-maps

Can I do something like this with Google Map API?

"get the location of all of the Apple Stores in New York City"

and get a JSON list of locations with coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"get a JSON list of locations with coordinates"

For this part of the question the answer is no - you need to use the reverse geocoding API with an address that will resolve.

[Bjorn Sallarp's code](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/) is an excellent example.

I don't *think* there is a way to specify that you want multiple matches, i.e. all Apple stores in a region.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You might, if you are lucky, find the information in [Google Fusion tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/) or from some web service like [mapusers](http://mapusers.com/)